# Bind event to object in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events

I have a `<div>` element, which should adjust width + height according to the document properties. I need to resize the `<div>` whenever the user scrolls inside the window.

Is there a possibility to bind the events to this specific object?

```js
var instance = (function() {
  var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth || 0,
    y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight || 0,
    z = Math.max(g.scrollHeight || 0, e.scrollHeight || 0, g.offsetHeight || 0, e.offsetHeight || 0, g.clientHeight || 0, e.clientHeight || 0);

  // private
  function getMeById(id) {
    return d.getElementById(id);
  };

  // public
  return {
    updateContainer: function(id) {
      console.log('updateContainer');
      var container = getMeById(id);
      container.style.position = 'absolute';
      container.style.width = x + 'px';
      container.style.minHeight = z + 'px';
    },
    bindScroll: function() {
      w.addEventListener('scroll', updateContainer(), false);
    }
  };

})();
instance.updateContainer("test");

/* @TODO: Bind events to object
  w.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    console.log('resize');
    var container = getMeById("test");
    updateContainer(container);
  }, true);

  w.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log('scroll');
    var container = getMeById("test");
    updateContainer(container);
  }, true);
  */
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

As you can see from the `bindScroll()` function it makes no sense right now.
Is there anyway to achieve the task?

Comment: The variable `w` only exists in the closure, not in global scope where your commented code is. `window.addEventListener` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You may pass the id into the eventListener callback through binding it to the updateContainer:

```
updateContainer: function(id) {
  console.log('updateContainer');
  var container = getMeById(id);
  container.style.position = 'absolute';
  container.style.width = x + 'px';
  container.style.minHeight = z + 'px';
},
bindScroll: function(id) {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateContainer.bind(this,id), false);
}
```

So one can do:

```
instance.bindScroll("testcontainer");
```

Note: x and z are not *live* so you may reload the values...

---

If you add more and more functions, your code could get difficult to manage. You could use inheritance and a constructor instead:

```
function instance(id){
 this.el=document.querySelector(id);
}
instance.prototype={
 bindScroll:function(){
  window.addEventListener("scroll",this.update.bind(this),false);
  return this;
  },
  update: function() {
  var container = this.el;
  container.style.position = 'absolute';
  container.style.width = x + 'px';
  container.style.minHeight = z + 'px';
  return this;
}
};
```

So you could do:

```
var test=new instance("#test")
test.update().bindScroll();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Is it possible to transform this code into a working live example?

I should add that this supposed to be an ad template, which gets injected from third party server into the site's DOM.

Comment: @AppRoyale im currently on a *StackSnippets not supported* device... so i may do when i am

Comment: That would be great and highly appreciated.